# A formula to equalize win chances

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I writing a game that has characters with few parameters: agility, strength and luck.
Agility allows a person to escape a hit, luck allows to do a critical hit (double the hit damage) and strength is the damage amount the character makes. As well, each character has health points such that total HP = health point * 6.

I wonder if it possible to write a formula to equalize the chances of two characters with same amount of parameters to win? For example,

| Parameter | A char | B char | C char |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Strength | 6 | 3 | 3 |
| Luck | 3 | 6 | 3 |
| Agility | 3 | 3 | 6 |
| Health Points | 5 | 5 | 5 |
| Total HP | 30 | 30 | 30 |

Ideally, each one of them should have equal chances to win.
I tried to calculate the chances of critical hit and escape: x_t = x_a / (x_a + x_b) where x is the relevant parameter. Then I tried to find a way through calculating the amount of hits needed to kill an opponent (opponentTotalHP / myStrength) and playing around with this factor to adjust the chances of escaping/making critical hit, but always ended up with big disbalance in either strong vs. agile, strong vs. lucky or lucky vs. agile win chances.

The fight mechanics are as following:
In each round a character hits his opponent. The opponent can either accept the damage or escape the hit according to its escaping chances. If hit, the damage can be doubled according to the crit chances.

So when a strong char fights an agile one and their sum of parameters equal, I need the agile to have bigger escaping chances to eventually be able to make as much damage as the strong one in average.

Comment: Depending on what you want, you may be over-complicating.  For example, is [Strength $= 6$, Luck $= 3$] to be regarded as *equivalent* to [Strength $= 3$, Luck $= 6$]?  Assuming so, assign to each person the sum of their attributes (i.e. $S_x$).  Then, one possible formula for person's A's chances to beat person B is $$\frac{S_A}{S_A + S_B}.$$

Comment: @user2661923 hi! Thanks for your comment. I've added some explanation regarding the fight mechanics.

Comment: What are you asking us to do, exactly? Do you want use to come up with functions $p_\text{avoid}(\text{agility}_A,\text{agility}_B)$ and $p_\text{crit}(\text{luck}_A,\text{luck}_B)$, determining the probabilities of dodging and critical strikes as a function of the relevant stats, so that two characters with equal stat totals have roughly equal chances of winning? That is, are you asking us to help design your game for you?

Comment: @MikeEarnest I'm not sure it has to do with game design and that's not what I'm asking. I'm asking about a way I could calculate the factors of the parameters such that P(a1,l1,s1)=P(a2,l2,s2)